# Java 8 how to read file twice and fix java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java-8, bufferedreader, filereader, ioexception

I am trying to read a text file twice in order to calculate an average (`calcAverage`) and then  to filter on the average to get a results list (`processFile`). When the second step is run the exception,
`java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed`
is thrown.

Below is a simplified version of my failing code and a unit-test to drive the code.

A parameter (`source`) of type `Reader` is passed into `App` from a unit test and is a `FileReader` to a text file. I dont know how to access the `File` handler  (or filename) from the `Reader` object to re-open it - I've tried implementing this inside App and this would fix the problem. The method signature of `runProcess (Reader source)` can not be changed - the other method signatures however can be.

I am using a `try-with-resources` block to open the Reader object and to read it through - its then closed automatically - which is all fine. I just need a way to re-open the file from the `Reader` to perform the filtering for pass-2.

I have read from similar questions, that the `BufferedReader`  is like an iterator and you can only read it once.

I have tried using the `mark()` and `reset()` methods on my `source` object, but this throws an exception that these aren't supported.

I could read the whole file into a List object and then use this to calculate both steps but I dont know how large my file is going to be and so if possible would like to try and find a solution using the approach below.

Does anyone know how I can implement this ?

```
    public class App {
    
        public static void runProcess(Reader source) {
            Collection<?> col = calcAverage(source);
            processFile(source).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
        }
    
        private static Collection processFile(Reader source)  {
            Collection<?> col = processFile(source, ((BufferedReader reader) -> reader.lines()
                    .skip(1)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            );
            return col;
        }
    
        private static Collection<?> calcAverage(Reader source) {
            Collection<?> col = processFile(source, ((BufferedReader reader) -> reader.lines()
                    .skip(1)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
            return col;
        }
    
        private static Collection<?> processFile(Reader source, BufferedReaderProcessor p){
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(source)) {
                return p.process(reader);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException f){
                f.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    
        @FunctionalInterface
        public interface BufferedReaderProcessor {
            Collection<?> process(BufferedReader b) throws IOException;
        }
    }
```

```
    public class AppTest {

       @Test
       public void shouldReadFileTwice() throws FileNotFoundException {
           App.runProcess(openFile("src/main/java/functions/example4/resources/list-of-fruits"));
       }

       private static Reader openFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
           return new FileReader(new File(filename));
       }

    }
```

Comment: `processFile()` loads the file into a collection, so it looks like the file is small enough to hold in memory. Easiest thing might be to do that first, and just process the loaded values, so you only read the file once.

Comment: `calcAverage` closes `source`, you can't use it after that. You could remove processFile from runProcesss, make it public, and change shouldReadFileTwice to have a second line that is `App.processFile(openFile())`. You could also have runProcess read the lines into a collection, then pass that collection to both calcAverage and processFile, this way you only open and read the file once into memory then pass it around.

Comment: Besides that, your exception handlers do all the same and `catch(Exception ex)` will catch all other exceptions anyway. So the other handlers are obsolete (not that `return null;` was a good way to handle it though).

Comment: @Holger thank you for that. Do you have a better suggestion for handling the exception than returning null ?

Comment: @John Bayko  I may end up implementing it this way if I cant get a better suggestion - thanks.

Comment: @Quantic thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately splitting the method as you suggest is not an option available to me.

Comment: Think about how you expect the caller to deal with an exceptional situation. At the moment, they do not check the result for `null`…

Comment: @Holger the problem is I am returning a Collection containing a domain specific object with a name (String) and a Quantity (long)....do I want to re-use this to return an error code for example by putting errorName in name and an error code in quantity ? another option would be to throw an exception and make the caller handle it...or just return an empty collection - I guess this would be the cleanest option?

Comment: “throw an exception and make the caller handle it” is the cleanest option. Returning an empty collection is only feasible if either, an empty collection can’t occur in the non-exception case or treating the exception case and an empty collection the same is valid for the application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't use try with resources. It calls `close` on its BufferedReader which causes all the incapsulated readers to be closed.
I.e. it closes `BufferedReader`, `Reader` and `FileReader`.

When you invoke `calcAverage` in `App::runProcess` it closes all the readers. Then you're trying to read closed `Reader` when calling `processFile` on the next line.